# можно ли  в качестве аргумента передать функции имя текстового потока?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос, можно ли  в качестве аргумента передать функции имя текстового потока:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int funk(string a, int size)
{               
    // Сюда в качестве аргументa добавить output
    // в теле функции результат вычислений записать в output
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, s;

    string a;

    ifstream input("input.txt");
    ofstream output("output.txt");

    getline(input, a);

    s = a.length();

    funk(a, s);
}
```

Прошу помочь, и извините если вопрос поставлен глупо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int funk (string a, int size, ostream &output); // передаем ссылку на объект класса ostream
```

Потоки — это тоже объекты.

P.S. Подробнее про [`ostream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/).